# GWT - Annotated time line chart with zooming, scrollbar and navigator

Tags: gwt, charts, scrollbar, navigator, google-finance

I am looking for a GWT extension for displaying a Google finance-like chart. (features like zooming, scroll-bar and navigator are required)I want to stay away from flash. I have looked at GWT Highcharts. Anything else worth considering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [dygraph](http://dygraphs.com/) to be a good solution. It has a gwt wrapper as well.

[An example here](http://rowsandcolumns.blogspot.com/2012/04/gwt-dygraph-example-using-visualization.html)

Answer (score 2):

Why not [Google's Own Annotated Timeline](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html)? It is already integrated into GWT's Visualization library, and it's EXACTLY the chart you described. Though it *is* flash-based, it's the best one around (IMO). I've never been a fan of using unsupported charts like Highcharts, but if you're completely against using Flash, that's probably your best option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Google Finance charting.

For annotated time-lines, the [Simile Timeline](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/) project is just great.  It's really mature, pure javascript, and has lots of documentation & examples.   Plus, there are a set of GWT Wrappers available for it in [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/gwtsimiletimeline/).

But, it won't really show a conventional xy line chart.

Update:
Aaah, I've just seen there is a [GWT wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/gwtsimiletimeplot/) for the [Simile TimePlot](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeplot/), which does look  more like an xy line chart.

Answer (score 1):

Annotated time line GWT is certainly not supported.

You will find that the flash control is a closed black box, and errors and faults just drift away.  No messages, no way out and no one will respond.

While at least with highstock, you have some hope as you have the source.  And folks there at least respond.

Also the flash control does not seem to play nice with apple.  So you won't have support for chrome or safari on a mac (does seem to work with firefox on the mac).